# safari problems with dom:loaded event

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, prototypejs

I have a small problem which I can't seem to find a solution to. The problem is that the following code works in FF but doesn't in Safari. Probably it is a rookie mistake, but I have been struggling now for two days and it is really getting on my nerves.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var settings = functionToReadSettings();
 document.observe('dom:loaded', function () {   
  functionToInit(settings);             
 });
</script>
```

The error I get in Safari is in functionToInit. It says that settings in undefined. I tried changing the places - both the settings definition and the call to functionToInit to be in the dom:loaded and both to be outside of it, but then it doesn't work in FF also.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Here is the `functionToReadSettings` :

```
functionToReadSettings: function () {
 new Ajax.Request('readSettings.php', {
  method:'get',
  onSuccess: function(transport){
   settings = transport.responseText.evalJSON(true);
  }
 });
 return settings;
}
```

Comment: Then problem may lie in `functionToReadSettings` as well.

Comment: @kirilloid The `functionToReadSettings` works when I call it separately both in Safari and FF. I don't seem to understand the execution order of these functions. Shouldn't it be in order of appearance?!

Comment: This should work as it is in your code now. Order is ok currently.

Comment: @kirilloid Can it be because of `functionToReadSettings` makes an `Ajax.Request` to get the settings from a file? Is it possible that in Safari it makes the `Ajax.Request` after the execution of the script? Really can't figure why it works in FF and not in Safari...

Comment: If request is synchronous, then 'dom:loaded' binding shouldn't be executed earlier. If it is asynchronous, how do you return a value from function functionToReadSettings?

Comment: @kirilloid The request is asynchronous as far as I can tell. I edited the question to include the `functionToReadSettings`

Comment: @kirilloid Спасибо, I guess. It was really because of the asynchronous call. I changed it to synchronous and now it works. Thank you very much. But how can I make it work with asynchronous also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, syncrhonisation isn't trivial task in js.
I don't know, whether such features are implemented in prototype, but there's another interesting library for such things:
http://onilabs.com/presentations/OSCON2010/par-fork-join.html